# What is the terminology for "self-referral" integrals in calculus?

Tags: calculus, terminology, integration

In the topic of integration and anti-derivatives in Calculus we come across cases where the attempt at integration by parts brings us back to the original integral, the most basic example being $\int e^{a x} \cos(b x) \,dx$. Is there a standard name for this type of integrals? I have been calling them "self-referral", but the only usage of this expression that I can find is in health insurance! Have  you seen a name in standard textbooks? I have seen "circular integrals" online. What do you call them? Does anyone call it "self-referential"? (Stewart does not have a name for it. Self-referential is an expression in logic. Circular integral might be used for contour integrals.)

Comment: I have never heard of a term for such a thing, nor do I think that they are important enough to bother with a specific name.  However, I would avoid the term "circular integral", as I would understand such an integral to either be an integral over a circle, or an integral related to some specific subset of elliptic integrals (not that I know what specific set this would be---that would just be my assumption about the term).

Comment: "self-referential" seems fine. I love how those turn into algebra problems, which is part of what I emphasize.

Comment: Giving it a name would give the (wrong) impression that it's a feature of the integral itself, whereas it's only a feature of this particular technique we're using to derive a closed form expression for this integral. PS. Justin Skycak's answer provides a name which is free of this issue.

Comment: Note the example you gave in your question can also be solved by using complex numbers which might be faster than the self-referential integral you speak of. I can't remember if this idea was in Stewart's Calculus text as well. Look at $$e^{x(i+1)}=e^x\cos x +ie^x \sin x$$ and then take the real or imaginary part. Hope this is another tool for your integral solving!

Comment: In my high school calculus class we called it "recovering the integral back".

Comment: Call me a simpleton, but my programming background tells me that you arrive at an equation involving recursion.

Comment: On Mathematics Stack Exchange, it was referred to as ["Integration by parts with déjà vu"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26325/does-integration-by-parts-with-deja-vu-have-a-name). I found this terminology amusing enough that I use it myself whenever I tutor school students.

Comment: A colleague at my university calls them "ninja integrals" (the result seems to appear out of nothing), and I have adopted that term.

Comment: FWIW, he German name for these integrals translates literally to “phoenix from the ashes” or just “phoenix”. That doesn’t seem to be used in English though.

Answer (score 10):

To my knowledge, this is most commonly known as ["cyclic" integration by parts](https://www.google.com/search?q=cyclic%20integration%20by%20parts&tbm=vid).

Comment: Seems like a relatively new name. I can't find this in any books. And the earliest such use of this name I could find was this 2012-09-11 video: https://www.educreations.com/lesson/view/cyclic-integration-by-parts/1469863/

Answer (score 1):

From [Does integration by parts with "deja vu" have a name?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26325):

- Sheard ("Trick or Technique?", [2009](https://maa.org/sites/default/files/Sheard-CMJ0917264.pdf)) calls it the *one-step algebra trick*;
- OP says he saw it called *integration by parts with "déjà vu"*;
- Glen Wheeler suggests calling it *absorption*.